# getting 'array' or 'Resource id #5'

Tags: php, mysql, database

So, I want to get a column to a variable.

I tried 2 methodes

`mysql_query`
and
`mysql_fetch_array`

At `mysql_query` I get `Resource id #5`.

And

At `mysql_fetch_array` I get `array`.
Does some one knows how to fix this?

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
```

Comment: no one use mysql_* functions anymore. Try mysqli_* functions or pdo instead

Comment: @e4c5 correction, no one who likes kittens uses `mysql_*` anymore, because for every use of `mysql_*` a kitten is killed

Comment: The values are in the array. I'm sure you can figure out how to read the values of an array.

Comment: what do you want/expect to get? what you have described is how those functions work. [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) returns a mysql resource while [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) returns an array

Comment: This question is moot since the OP should rewrite his code using MySQLi or PDO instead, anyway. When he then checks at [php.net](http://php.net) for how to use one of them, he will also find some excellent examples on how to use it.

Comment: ...and after he switches to one of the more secure extensions, he can also use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to remove the possibility of any [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: @Memor-X years ago I wrote an entire e-commerce using `mysql_*` and it is still running ...then my site is killing lots of poor kittens....note that it is a pet food shop

Comment: @CliffBurton to be fair years ago `mysql_*` proably wasn't deprecated. should look into chnaging it over to save you some work if you upgrade to PHP7....though the fact your e-commerce website is a pet food store is f***** hilarious that i think i wet myself laughing. now you just need to say you also sell Dim Sims as a snack food

Comment: Hello dear are you begginer in the php codeing then you shoul work with mysqli rather then mysql . But if you are working on mysql or mysqli then read here how to reterive data from database .

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: Yes @Memor-X, it wasn't still deprecated, and I'm not going to change anything until the site owner asks me something, there are about 700k lines of code, it would be a suicide! And...no, but I sell special tissues for incontinence problems. Would you be interested? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have column with name as 'firstname'. Then you can go with this

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userId=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
$firstname = $userRow[0]['firstname'];
echo $firstname;
```

If you get multiple rows in result, you can get all rows by loop.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to call the column name from a table where the value of that column is equal to a variable? If so...

The easiest way I can think of to resolve this would be to so a search through all the tables for the value you look for based on columns and return the value. This function should help accomplish this task:

```
    function columnToVariable($conn, $table, $variable){//SET PARAMETERS (CONNECTION STRING, TABLE NAME, VARIABLE SEARCH)
      $sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $table).";"; // SQL STATEMENT
      $result = $conn->query($sql); // RESULTS OF ALL ROWS
      $field = array(); // ARRAY WITH COLUMNS
      if($result->num_rows > 0){ // CHECK IF RESULTS FOUND
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ // SET RESULTS TO ARRAY
          array_push($field, $row['Field']); // APPEND ARRAY WITH FIELD NAME
        }
      }
      foreach($field as $return){ // ITERATE THROUGH FIELD NAMES
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $table)." WHERE ".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $return)." = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $variable)."';"; // SQL STRING
        $result = $conn->query($sql); // QUERY RESULTS
        if($result->num_rows > 0){ // IF FOUND, RETURN VALUE
          return $return; // RETURN VALUE
        }
      }  
    }
```